# How to install Archiva or Artifactory or Nexus in my Tomcat Server

Tags: maven, tomcat, nexus, artifactory, archiva

I'm looking for a repository to put some of my java libs and integrate with Maven. So far the best options that I have found are Archiva, Artifactory and Nexus open source. What I need is to install any of those in my own Tomcat Server, because I have a online Tomcat Server with in a Cpanel host. Those solutions all came with a embbed server. I need to install in my own. Archiva has a tutorial but I fail to suceed. Artifactory has one too but for the 2x version, with is really out of date. Nexus I fail to even find a war file. Someone have install any of those in your own Tomcat (that host other apps)? Do you have any tips or something?

Comment: Artifactory no longer officially supports installation on a servlet container (Tomcat, WebSphere etc.) but is rather bundled with  an embedded Tomcat.

Comment: too bad, thanks for the answer